# Good probability reading for undergraduates

Tags: probability, reference-request

Do people have any good books I can suggest to undergraduates who find basic probability courses a little boring? It would be nice if there are books that do not require measure theory, and have a combinatorial or dynamical systems flavor.

Answer (score 1):

You could try "Probability and Random Processes" by Grimmett & Stirzacker, ([Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Random-Processes-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198572220/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1540727604&sr=1-5&keywords=probability.)).
This is the standard (non measure theoretic) text for what you are looking to study.